# How can I stop grass from lagging my game?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am attempting to add grass to my game.

[image]

However it unfortunately drops the FPS from 60+ to only 36. If I crash my ship right into the terrain, it can even go down to 32.

I've tried not rendering grass further away.
[image]

However it still is a huge hit to the game FPS. Remember that without it my FPS more-than doubles!

The grass uses the same model as the trees - A billboard which is turned to always face the camera.
[image]
And obviously I remove transparent bits with the fragment shader.

I have heard of techniques like "Clumping", however I would have no idea how to do that or even why it would help performance.

I use this code for rendering:

```
TexturedModel texturedModel = TerrainDemo.textModel;
    RawModel model = texturedModel.getRawModel();
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    FloatBuffer buf = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16 * 4);
    // Get your current model view matrix from OpenGL. 
    glTranslatef(location.x * TerrainDemo.scale, location.y, location.z * TerrainDemo.scale);
    glRotatef(90, 1f, 0f, 0f);
    GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, buf);
    buf.rewind();

    buf.put(0, 1.0f);
    buf.put(1, 0.0f);
    buf.put(2, 0.0f);

    buf.put(4, 0.0f);
    buf.put(5, 1.0f);
    buf.put(6, 0.0f);

    buf.put(8, 0.0f);
    buf.put(9, 0.0f);
    buf.put(10, 1.0f);

    GL11.glLoadMatrix(buf);


    GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getVaoID());
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, TerrainDemo.texModel.getTexture().getID());
    glScalef(15f, 15f, 15f);
    glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 0.5f);
    glRotatef(90, 0f, 1f, 0f);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, model.getVertexCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

How can I reduce the lag created by the grass?

(Quick note: I removed the terrain texture for demonstration purposes so you could see the grass easier)

UPDATE: I just tried culling the back face of grass, but it appeared to make no difference. Even if I culled BOTH faces there was no difference.

Comment: It's impossible to say for sure, but traditionally grass has been fillrate intensive. Judging from your screenshot it doesn't look particularly demanding, but you might have a low-end GPU. If it is a fillrate limitation, you're actually approaching the problem backwards - you would want to limit the amount of nearby grass that you draw because it fills more pixels than distant grass. If it's not a fillrate limitation, then the way you're batching the grass geometry might be to blame.

Comment: As another recommendation, if you haven't written a ton of OpenGL code for this project yet, consider switching to the OpenGL core profile.  You're already using VAOs, so the rest of the changes may be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since @DietrichEpp already covered some higher level approaches, I'll focus on some direct suggestions on your current code. In case you're not ready to make the jump, I think you could get substantial improvements from just fixing the first item.

1. There is a `glGetFloat(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, ...)` call in your rendering code. You should **never** have `glGet*()` calls in any speed critical parts of the code that are executed very frequently. They can be very harmful to performance.

   In this case, you seem to try to extract and the translation part from the current transformation matrix. Since you're specifying all the transformations yourself, it should be reasonably easy to just calculate the necessary translation, and apply it.
2. You're creating a buffer. Object creation is fairly expensive, and I would try to avoid it inside a rendering loop. And I believe this might create a native buffer, which is probably even more overhead. If you really do need a buffer, create it once, and reuse it when drawing each object.
3. There are a few calls that look to be the same each time. If you loop over this code sequence, pull them outside the loop. For example:

   ```
   glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
   ...
   GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
   GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, TerrainDemo.texModel.getTexture().getID());
   ```
4. Get rid of the fixed function matrix functionality, build the matrices yourself, and make one `glUniformMatrix4fv()` call for specifying them.
5. You're not using VAOs effectively:

   ```
   GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getVaoID());
   GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
   GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
   ```

   Attribute pointer enable/disable state is part of the VAO state. So you only have to make the `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` calls once, when you set up the VAO.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of objects to draw, and you're doing a `glDrawElements()` (plus ~10 state changes) per object.  If you have 1,000 patches of grass, that's something like 10,000 API calls into OpenGL.  This is generally known to be the slow way of doing things, and when you do things this way, you'll generally run into CPU limitations before you run into GPU limitations.

### The slow way

This is the slow way of drawing things to the screen.

```
for (obj : all objects) {
    glUseProgram(...);
    glUniform(...);
    glBindVertexArray(...);
    glDrawElements(...);
}
```

### A faster way

The goal here is to make the same number of OpenGL API calls no matter how many patches of grass you want to draw.

```
int count = 0;
for (obj : all grass) {
    add obj data to buffer;
    count += 1;
}
glUseProgram(...);
glUniform(...);
glBindVertexArray(...);
glDraw?????(..., count);
```

### Method 1: instancing

One way you can achieve this is by using instancing.  With instancing, you call `glDrawElementsInstanced()` and tell it how many copies of the model you want it to draw.  You'll need to figure out a way to get information about each object, there are a few different methods.

1. A typical, easy method is to use attributes with the divisor set.  These attributes will specify data that is per-object instead of per vertex.  `glVertexAttribDivisor()` will set the divisor.
2. Another way is to put the per-object attributes into a uniform buffer, which you can index with `gl_InstanceID`.
3. You could also put the per-object attributes in a buffer texture, and index it with `gl_InstanceID`.

### Method 2: geometry shader

Since your model is a simple billboard, you can generate the entire thing inside a geometry shader.  With this approach, you ditch the model, and create a vertex array with one point for each grass object.  You call `glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, ...)`, and then the geometry shader transforms each point into a quad (actually, a triangle strip with two triangles).

### Recommendations

My recommendation is to use the geometry shader approach, since it's so good at handling billboards.  If your grass model were more complicated, I would recommend instancing instead.

I also noticed that you're mixing the fixed-function pipeline with modern VAOs.  This is... a bit weird.  You'll probably have to ditch your use of `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX` and friends, at least when you're drawing grass.

Comment: It's a hard decision, but I think I'm going to accept the other answer, since it helps me to solve the current issue wheras yours suggests some great new techniques I could use. Very helpful answer - Thanks!

Comment: Full support for the geometry shader approach. Then you supply an array of points of each grass position and emit a quad. Supply additional information if needed. If you have several grass types you can use arraytexture.